# Mac drops USB port with Time Machine SSD Card when it sleeps

Tags: mac, time-machine, usb, sleep-wake

My Mac (running 10.13.6) constantly drops connectivity with my SSD card (used for Time Machine backups) connected to a USB port when the Mac goes to sleep mode.  I then have to unplug the card and replug it in the USB, then after the Mac recognizes it, rerun the Sandisk Unlocker & enter the PW.  Then... at some point Time Machine will start running. This essentially makes Time Machine unusable, as I can't go through this process every hour or two just to keep a background backup system working. Is there a fix to correct the Mac losing connectivity with remote USB drives when going into sleep mode?
Thanks!

Comment: With your SSD attached to your Mac, please run the following command and update your question with a www.PasteBin.com link to the output: `ioreg -lw0 -p IOUSB`

Comment: Do you have PowerNap enabled? System Preferences > Energy Saver > Enable Power Nap checkbox.

Comment: I do not have PowerNap enabled.

Comment: @BillC Just wanted to ping and see if you've had a chance to get the `ioreg` data.

Comment: @pion, I did run the command, but am reluctant to post output that may include critical data to a site I am unfamiliar with that may allow for hack or corruption of my computer.  I don't doubt your integrity, but am not familiar enough with the details in the output to know what all is there, and anyone going to Pastebin might be able to exploit it.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: @IconDaemon - I enabled PowerNap, and based on some research that may well be the problem, so am trying that now.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @BillC All `ioreg` does is print a human-parseable description of the IOKit registry, which is a tree structure maintained in the kernel that keeps track of all devices (both internal and external) and their hierarchical relationships. The specific command I gave you will dump the USB device tree and each node's properties. Your prudence is wise and I encourage you to examine the output carefully so that you can be sure that no personal data is being leaked. The most we'd know is the volume name(s) of any storage media, and you can redact that. Read `man ioreg` for more info on the command.